# Why am in getting an " Illegal characters in path" error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to save data to a file like this:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream("c:\temp", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        file.Close();
        file.Close();
```

And I get this error:

Illegal characters in path. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in your file path:

```
 FileStream("c:\\temp", ...
```

`\t` is the character for a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Try "c:\\temp"  -  "c:\temp" is the string [c] [:] [tab character] [e] [m] [p]  which is almost surely not the filename you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the following

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
FileStream file = new FileStream("c:\\temp", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
```

'\' is an escape character, so you can't use it directly